# Package importing/compiling is not working

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a small project. It consists of two classes, `Fraction.java`, that represents a mathematical fraction and provides some methods for simple calculations, and `Main.java`, which contains the main method that creates two fractions and does some calculations. The project structure is as follows:

```
MyFractionProject
|
+-------src
         |
         +------fractionpackage
                       |
                       +-------Fraction.java
                       +-------Main.java
```

Since both classes are in the same package I don't have to add package declarations right? All I have to to is import `Fraction.java` to `Main.java`, e.g.:

```
import Fraction;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(...)
        ...
```

Yet this isn't working. When I try to compile both classes from `MyFractionProject/src/fractionpackage`the fraction class compiles fine, but `javac Main.java` gives me this error:

```
localhost:fractionpackage MyUserName$ javac Fraction.java
localhost:fractionpackage MyUserName$ javac Main.java
Main.java:1: '.' expected
import Fraction;
        ^
Main.java:1: ';' expected
import Fraction;
         ^
2 errors
```

I know this is a common beginner question, but I haven't really found a concise explanation of which classes from which packages have to be compiled in what order from which working directory to which classes folder. Often respondents just jump around wildly in the directory or the class path, which is not helpful to a beginner at all.

I thought I had chosen the most basic setup possible, and that even that isn't working is really frustrating. Could someone have a look over it and give me the concrete instructions (with the respective working dirs) that would make this project run?

Comment: `Fraction` is not the correct *fully qualified* class name. Research what a "fully qualified name" is, then you understand the problem and know the solution.

Comment: If classes are in a package, they should have a package declaration.

Comment: this has nothing to do with packages. You have a syntax error missing a . and a ;. Unless you actually post the actual code, no one can tell you what the error is.

Comment: Ok so what I've got so far is that you never have to import classes from the same package, and that importing from other packages requires the fully qualified name like `package.subpackage.Class`. But what is the base directory for that path? Does Java just assume that there is always a `src` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import other classes in your package: if you have classes C1, C2, ... Cn in your package p; then all of these C1, ... can use each other without any import statements.

You only need to import classes from **different** packages.

Thus when *Fraction* is in the same package as *Main*; then just remove those import statements; and you should be good!

Comment: No, that gives `Main.java:5: cannot find symbol`

Comment: Sorry, that was indeed another mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are in same package, then you don't need to import anything just create an object for the other class. Classes must be imported only when they are to be accessed from another package.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally new to java too but my initial guess would be that you don't have to import the class explicitly as you said they belong to the same package. So just remove that import Fraction;

Comment: That cannot find symbol is probably to do something in the Fraction class. Can you post the source code for us to see?

Comment: That was another error with the constructor, had nothing to do with the packages.

Comment: That wasn't me.